# Blazor Server save SignalR connection to database to prevent loss?

Tags: server, signalr, blazor

SignalR connection is connection between server and user and its "stored" in server memory.

There are some scenarios where SignalR is lost and user needs to reload the page.

1. When I need to restart the Server
2. When users sleeps his phone and get back to website after some time

**Is it somehow possible to save these SignalR connection instances to Database, so when i restart my server it will reload them into Memory and user is able to reconnect to his previous state ?**

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to persist the *connection*. What you need to persist is *app/user session state*. Go through this article below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server

If you are looking for mobile app style resume functionality, that is very hard to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

I persist the connected users. In scaled services there is no guarentee you will get the same instance of the server. There is a feature called auto reconnect you can look at on the hub context other than that you should configure your clients to reconnect by monitoring the connection state. Either way you will get a new connectionId.